# 64-bit Hardware Virtualization on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtualbox, hardware

I am trying to set up a SQL Server practice lab using VirtualBox and a trial copy of Windows Server 2K8 R2 in ISO format. I received an error message that states my processor does not support 64-bit hardware virtualization. Although I "Enabled" Intel ardware virtualization in the BIOS that still doesn't work. According to the Intel website, the processor does support VT-x, however the accelerated tab in VirtualBox is greyed out and no references to VT-x are mentioned in the settings options available to me.

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

I checked around ServerFault and couldn't find anything but if I missed an applicable post a link is great too. Specs below - if additional information is needed please comment and I will provide. Thanks in advance.

VirtualBox version - 4.1.18
Hardware - Lenovo B570 1068-A3U i3-2310M

Answer (score 4):

On some BIOSes, you not only need to enable hardware virtualization, but also the "execute disable bit", or whatever it's called in that specific BIOS; without it, some hypervisors just won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Probably while creating the new virtual computer you did not select Windows7 64bit. Create a new one and make sure that you have selected Windows 7(64 bit) from the drop down box.By default if you write windows 7 for name in version brings windows 7 (not 64bit).
[VirtualBox 64-bit guests](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

Answer (score 2):

this is an old question to which I am answering. I am having a similar issue using VirtualBox on Windows 8 pro (64bit).

In my case I had to "Disable" Execute Disable bit to make the Hardware Acceleration work. My MB manufacturer is ASUS and I have logged an inquiry to the issue too. I still havent found a way to make both Intel Virtualization and Execute Disable bit to work together.

I will keep the post updated so that someone searching can find it useful.

Comment: I had the same issue with the Acceleration tab being grayed out in VirtualBox with my ASUS Rampage GENE II motherboard.  As soon as I set the Execute Disable to Disable in the BIOS, the tab became available.  I hope this helps someone else.